# c++ multithreading shared resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to multithread a piece of code using the boost library. The problem is that each thread has to access and modify a couple of global variables. I am using mutex to lock the shared resources, but the program ends up taking more time then when it was not multithreaded. Any advice on how to optimize the shared access?

Thanks a lot!

In the example below, the *choose_ecount* variable has to be locked, and I cannot take it out of the loop and lock it for only an update at the end of the loop because it is needed with the newest values by the *inside* function.

```
for(int sidx = startStep; sidx <= endStep && sidx < d.sents[lang].size(); sidx ++){
    sentence s = d.sents[lang][sidx];
    int senlen = s.words.size();
    int end_symb = s.words[senlen-1].pos;

    inside(s, lbeta);
    outside(s,lbeta, lalpha);
    long double sen_prob = lbeta[senlen-1][F][NO][0][senlen-1];

    if (lambda[0] == 0){
        mtx_.lock();
        d.sents[lang][sidx].prob = sen_prob;
        mtx_.unlock();
    }

    for(int size = 1; size <= senlen; size++)
        for(int i = 0; i <= senlen - size ; i++)
        {
            int j = i + size - 1;
            for(int k = i; k < j; k++)
            {
                int hidx = i;   int head = s.words[hidx].pos;
                for(int r = k+1; r <=j; r++)
                {
                    int aidx = r;   int arg  = s.words[aidx].pos;
                        mtx_.lock();
                    for(int kids = ONE; kids <= MAX; kids++)
                    {
                        long double num = lalpha[hidx][R][kids][i][j] * get_choose_prob(s, hidx, aidx) *
                                lbeta[hidx][R][kids - 1][i][k] * lbeta[aidx][F][NO][k+1][j];
                        long double gen_right_prob = (num / sen_prob);

                        choose_ecount[lang][head][arg] += gen_right_prob; //LOCK
                        order_ecount[lang][head][arg][RIGHT] += gen_right_prob; //LOCK
                    }
                        mtx_.unlock();
                }
```

}

Comment: Can you lift the mutext out of the most inside loop and move it up a level?

Comment: Yes. That helped a bit.

Comment: The next question is whether you can move the mutex lock/unlock a couple more levels up to surround the for (int size = ... loop.  It appears that you do initialization then a quick loop through things then cycle back up, do some more initialization and then run through the loop again.  Also it would be nice to know how the function get_choose_prob is using its parameters and any globals to know whether it is doing something with side effects or not especially to the variable s.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have posted I can see only writes to choose_ecount and order_ecount. So why not use local per thread buffers to compute the sum and then add them up after the outermost loop and only sync this operation?

Edit:
If you need to access the intermediate values of choose_ecount how do you assure the correct intermediate value is present? One thread might have finished 2 iterations of its loop in the meantime producing different results in another thread.

It kind of sounds like you need to use a barrier for your computation instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely you're going to get acceptable performance using a mutex in an inner loop.  Concurrent programming is difficult, not just for the programmer but also for the computer.  A large portion of the performance of modern CPUs comes from being able to treat blocks of code as sequences independent of external data.  Algorithms that are efficient for single-threaded execution are often unsuitable for multi-threaded execution.

You might want to have a look at [`boost::atomic`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0_beta1/doc/html/atomic.html), which can provide lock-free synchronization, but the memory barriers required for atomic operations are still not free, so you may still run into problems, and you will probably have to re-think your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you divide your complete problem into chunks ranging from `startStep` to `endStep` to get processed by each thread.

Since you have that locked `mutex` there, you're effectively serializing all threads:
You divide your problem into some chunks which are processed in serial, yet unspecified order.
That is the only thing you get is the overhead for doing multithreading.

Since you're operating on `double`s, using atomic operations is not a choice for you: they're typically implemented for integral types only.

The only possible solution is to follow Kratz' suggestion to have a copy of `choose_ecount` and `order_ecount` for each thread and reduce them to a single one after your threads have finished.